# How to stop NAO robot to detect people automatically?

Tags: nao-robot

I am working on a project for NAO recording and I am trying to analyse the sound data. I set the head yaw as well as the pitch angle to a specified degree first and then start the recording process. A problem comes when somebody is facing to its camera, it will move its head and face to the person which is really annoyed   .
It seems that this face contact is run in default, could anybode teach me how to blind it? 
ALSO is it possible to stop the robot to shake its body when it rests?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to Autonomous Life - you can disable it from Choregraphe, from robot settings, or simply by pressing the chest button twice - see [the documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/family/nao_user_guide/nao_freeze.html).

Comment: Thankyou very much !  It works well now. That's what I need!